# Align equations in two columns with their own equation number

Tags: equations

I have four equations, and I'd like to display them in two rows and two columns. I also want them to have their own respective equation numbering. I've tried

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{equation}
    A=B
\end{equation}
\columnbreak
\begin{equation}
    C=D
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

But if I do that, they aren't aligned. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SE! You use `multicols` only for have two numbered equation in line? For this is better to use two minipages.

Comment: Just insert `\noindent` after `\begin{multicols}{2}`.

Comment: The \noindent worked wonders. Thx

Comment: Could you convert your comment to an answer @Mico ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the equations in the left- and right-hand columns have (roughly) equal heights, it suffices to insert the instruction

```
\noindent
```

after `begin{multicols}{2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Column-like separation of equations is possible with [`multicols`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicols), but also with other structures that allow for boxing content. For example, using `minipage`s or `tabular`s. As an example of the latter, consider:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}}
  \begin{equation}
    A = B + C
  \end{equation}
  &
  \begin{equation}
    C + D = E
  \end{equation} \\
  \begin{equation}
    E + F = G
  \end{equation}
  &
  \begin{equation}
    G = H + I
  \end{equation}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

One can adjust the vertical spacing around the equations as needed. Vertical rules have been added to indicate the actual columns and are purely for visualization purposes.